# Error populating dropdownlist from SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2012, web-config

So I have successfully add a data connection to my VS project and now I'm trying to populate the drop down menu that I created with the data from the tables coming from the database; however, when I run the code it says, "Login failed for use 'Username', on this line:

```
                    cmd.Connection.Open();
```

This is my C# code:

```
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Security;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
 using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace Test1234
    {
        public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                PopulateDDList1();
                //PopulateDDList2();
                //PopulateDDList2_1();
            }




            public void PopulateDDList1()
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [History]", new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Connection"]));
                cmd.Connection.Open();

                SqlDataReader ddlValues;
            ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DropDownList1.DataSource = ddlValues;
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Serial";
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Serial";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();

            cmd.Connection.Close();
            cmd.Connection.Dispose();

        }//end Populate 1
     }
}
```

This is the web.config code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>

    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ActioNetITInventoryConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=10.10.101.188;Initial Catalog=ActioNetITInventory;User ID=rails.sa;Password=ActioNet1234"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="Connection" value="Data Source=10.10.101.188;Initial Catalog=ActioNetITInventory;User ID=rails.sa;Password=***********;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

Comment: you can't provide login credentials ***and*** `integrated security = true`.  Why aren't you using an actual connection string rather than an app setting value?

Comment: also `ActioNet1234` lolol

Comment: Why are you selecting every single column from the History table. You are only using the Serial column. Talk about inefficient.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm just testing the database to get the connection string to work

Answer (score 0):

I think there error occures due to your connection string. Is there a reason that you don't use the servername but its IP?
By the way: You defined it twice in two different config sections..

If you're using the IP, then you have to add the port:

```
Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;
Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Alternatively you could use the standard way:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Or even better if possible: Use trusted connection:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;
```

Generally have a look here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: The problem was the password was set equals to = '*' and I think it was reading that instead of the password itself so I just input the ActioNet1234 password and now it works

Comment: You literally had the asterisks set as password? But additionally be sure to follow @Greg's advices as your code is not yet very robust.

Answer (score 0):

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Connection" value="Data Source=10.10.101.188;Initial Catalog=ActioNetITInventory;User ID=rails.sa;Password=***********;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Your connection string contains both a login & password as well as `Integrated Security=True`

If you are trying to log on with a named login/password, then either set `Integrated Security=False` or leave it out altogether

Answer (score 0):

You have several potential failure points, for instance:

- Calling `ExecuteReader` but not actually validating data, ie no `Null`.
- Potentially several Columns being returned, when you only need a `Key` and `Value`.
- Are you sure `Serial` is valid Column.
- Your connection includes integrated security and a login / password.  Use one or the other.  (Kritner's answer has good information and direction for this).

To make your code a bit more legible and robust, you could do the following:

```
public IList<TModel> GetModel<T>(string query) where TModel : new()
{
     var container = new List<T>();
     using(var connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnection))
          using(var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
          {
               connection.Open();
               using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                  while(reader.Read())
                  {
                       TModel model = new TModel();
                       var type = model.GetType();
                       var table = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(reader.GetName).ToArray();

                       foreach(var property in type.GetProperties())
                            foreach(var column in table)
                                 if(String.Compare(property.Name, column, true) == 0)
                                     if(!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal(property.Name)))
                                      property.SetValue(model, reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal(property.Name)), null);

                       container.Add(model);
                  }
          }
}
```

The following method will build your model, so you would simply do:

```
drpExample.DataSource = GetModel<Person>("SELECT * FROM [History]");
drpExample.DataBind();
```

You really shouldn't have a direct query like that, you should really use Parameters but this should get you started.  Also you will need the `DataKeyValue` and `DataKeyText` which I often apply to the front-end.  You would simply set the value to the correlated `Property` in your model.

Comment: I'll definitely look into this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment, you can't provide both `login credentials` and state `integrated security=true` - it's one or the other.

`Integrated Security` basically says "use the current domain credentials I'm logged into the system with."

That being said, you probably want it to look like this:

```
<add key="Connection" 
    value="Data Source=10.10.101.188;Initial Catalog=ActioNetITInventory;User ID=rails.sa;Password=ActioNet1234;"/>
```

Although the "Connection" seems redundant as you already have a connection string with the same information.  You can use that like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT * FROM [History]", 
    new SqlConnection(
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ActioNetITInventoryConnectionString"].ConnectionString)
    )
);
```

Comment: It's weird how I was not able to connect earlier using that same line of code and I tried it again and now it works! Thanks a bunch!